# loading data change to sql table by SSIS package

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a excel file in a folder, I'd like to design a SSIS package: when the excel data does not have any change, will not fire this SSIS package; when the excel data have update, insert or delete, will fire this SSIS package, and loading those change into a sql table, and send me a notice email at the same time. Could you please how to design this SSIS package (details)?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is the SLowly Changing Dimension component in SSIS. There is also a component called Send email task that will allow you to send the complex information. If you will have any further questions please let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much. SCD seemed only can make change in the original sql table, like add new columns with expire or current. I need to loading those excel changing into a sql table.

Comment: Let's do:

1. In Managemtn Studio. Create a table in your database that have the same atributes as you have in your Excel file.

2. In SSIS. Create a data reader component and point to the Excel file.

3. In SSIS. Create a SCD component and combine the data reader and created earlier table. Combine by the table key and point the changing atributes.
When you run the data flow task the SCD component will join the data from data reader with your destination table and will check if the value of each atribute from final destination table is different with the value from the data reader (excel file)